# Digging deeper into running .NET Core apps on IIS

Tags: vue.js, iis, .net-core, azure-devops

I've got a build and release pipeline on Azure DevOps that runs `dotnet publish` on a Vue + .NET Core application and moves it to a server where I plan to run it with IIS.

If I remote into said server, navigate to the folder where my app is, and run `dotnet App.dll`, it runs on localhost:5000 and looks good. But when I go to IIS Manager and start the website from there, I go to the URL that I've got a certificate setup for and I get a 403 or a 404.

1. What exactly is happening behind the scenes when I start a website on IIS Manager?
2. Can I run IIS commands myself via command line for the sake of troubleshooting? Is there a page where I can read about these commands?

Comment: Nothing happens when you start a website on IIS Manager. The actual initialization (ASP.NET Core module related) starts when the first request comes. You also need to learn what is Kestrel, what is IIS, and what is in-process/out-of-process hosting, https://blog.lextudio.com/a-closer-look-at-asp-net-core-execution-model-b3c332f6ed1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did find, in case anyone is reading this.

I needed to take a close look at the web.config that was being generated by the `dotnet publish` command, that's sort of where the magic is happening/what IIS is looking at.

After that, I needed to install the .NET Core hosting bundle on the server IIS was running on.